# How to sort min value using xslt?

Tags: xslt

below is my xml file called test.xml

```
<products>
    <supplier>
        <supplierid>1001</supplierid>
        <totalprice>30</totalprice>
        <items>
            <item>Pen</item> 
            <price>10</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Pencil</item> 
            <price>5</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Bag</item> 
            <price>15</price>
        </items>
    </supplier>
    <supplier>
        <supplierid>1001</supplierid>
        <totalprice>23</totalprice>
        <items>
            <item>Pencil</item> 
            <price>8</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Pen</item> 
            <price>5</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Bag</item> 
            <price>10</price>
        </items>        
    </supplier>
    <supplier>
        <supplierid>1001</supplierid>
        <totalprice>24</totalprice>
        <items>
            <item>Paper Box</item> 
            <price>7</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Pen</item> 
            <price>4</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Bag</item> 
            <price>13</price>
        </items>
    </supplier>
    <supplier>
        <supplierid>1002</supplierid>
        <totalprice>26</totalprice>
        <items>
            <item>Sharpner Box</item> 
            <price>7</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Pen</item> 
            <price>4</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Bag</item> 
            <price>15</price>
        </items>
    </supplier>
</products>
```

I need to take output like below using xsl 1.0 or 2.0

```
<products>
    <supplier>
        <supplierid>1001</supplierid>
        <totalprice>23</totalprice>
        <items>
            <item>Pencil</item> 
            <price>8</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Pen</item> 
            <price>5</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Bag</item> 
            <price>10</price>
        </items>        
    </supplier>
    <supplier>
        <supplierid>1001</supplierid>
        <totalprice>24</totalprice>
        <items>
            <item>Paper Box</item> 
            <price>7</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Pen</item> 
            <price>4</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Bag</item> 
            <price>13</price>
        </items>
    </supplier>
    <supplier>
        <supplierid>1002</supplierid>
        <totalprice>26</totalprice>
        <items>
            <item>Sharpner Box</item> 
            <price>7</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Pen</item> 
            <price>4</price>
        </items>
        <items>
            <item>Bag</item> 
            <price>15</price>
        </items>
    </supplier>
</products>
```

1. Sort less price from "same suppliers" for example `<supplierid>1001</supplierid>`
2. Based on there sub nodes `<items>`
3. 1001/23 and 1001/30 is same based on there `<items><item>`. we need to remove 1001/30 from the list. because it is high price

Comment: can you explain bit more clear? In your input & output, there is no much differences too..

Comment: Is it totalprice you like to sort on?

Comment: Based on there <totalprice>. for example supplier:1001 has 2 total price 30 and 23 . This total price comes based on there <items>. If <items> is same in there list. sort that with cheap price based on totalprice

Comment: @user475464: supplier 1001 has 3 total price 30, 23, 24. But in the output xml, one supplier 1001 with total price 30 node is missing. Is that intentionally removed or by mistake?

Comment: we need to remove that. because there <items> comes twice in totalprice 30 amd 23

Comment: Will each supplier always have exactly 3 items?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption that you like to sort suppliers based on their totalprice:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<products>
  <xsl:for-each select="products/supplier">  
    <xsl:sort select="totalprice" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>  
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>  
  </xsl:for-each> 
</products>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Based on there <totalprice>. for example supplier:1001 has 2 total price 30 and 23 . This total price comes based on there <items>. If <items> is same in there list. sort that with cheap price based on totalprice

Answer (score 0):

This will first sort based on `supplierid` and secondly based on their `totalprice`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:sort select="supplierid"/>  <!-- 1st level sorting -->
                <xsl:sort select="totalprice"/>  <!-- 2nd level sorting -->
                <xsl:sort select="price"/>       <!-- 3rd level sorting -->
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note:** You can use a free online tool called [Online XSLT Test Tool](http://xslttest.appspot.com/) to test your xml/xslt files.

Comment: sort supplierid with there distinct items

Comment: The above xslt sorts by supplierid, e.g.: 1001,1001,1001,1002, etc.. and then sorts by the total price, e.g: 1001/23, 1001/24, 1001/30, 1002/26. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: 1001/23 and 1001/30 is same based on there <items><item>. we need to remove 1001/30 from the list. because it is high price

Comment: I added a 3rd level sorting based on `price`.

Comment: 1001/23 and 1001/30 is same based on there <items><item>. we need to remove 1001/30 from the list. because it is high price